# fastest way to recursively read files in subfolders

Tags: python, pandas, glob

I'm searching a quicker way to go through several folders (and subfolders) and read some files

```
files = [f for f in glob.glob(filepath + "*.csv", recursive=True)]
for f in files:
    ...
```

Comment: use ```pathlib.rglob```. Ur code should look like :```files = Path(filepath).rglob('"*.csv")```. u can iterate through the files generator and run ur computations.[doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob)

Comment: use [os.walk](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm)